# How to match VirtualBox VMs to Vagrant VMs?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I use Vagrant with Oracle VirtualBox and I'm trying to clear up space on my laptop.  I've noticed that I have a number of directories in my ~/VirtualBox VMs directory that are taking up a lot of room.  The names of these directories don't match up with anything in my Vagrantfiles.  What I also don't quite understand is that I have two VMs that I am able to start up but if I run the "vagrant global-status" command, it tells me "There are no active Vagrant environments on this computer!"

How do I determine which of the VirtualBox VM directories I'm still using and which ones can be deleted using the Oracle VirtualBox Manager?  Should I just delete everything and start over?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be one way to do it:

1. Go into each directory, run "vagrant status", halt the machine (if it's running), and then destroy it.  This will delete the associated directory in ~/VirtualBox VMs.
2. After you've done this for all know Vagrantfile directories, run the Oracle VirtualBox application and Remove each remaining machine.